# Is there any R package supporting learning multiple sequences?

Tags: r, machine-learning, sequence, hidden-markov-models, markov-chains

R [Markov chain](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/markovchain/) and [HMM](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/HMM/) packages are nice packages, but both of them only support learn a model from **one sequence** (correct me if I am wrong).

Is there any package allow user to learn a model from multiple sequences?